# How do I compile my C++ code with anaconda boost?

Tags: c++, boost, anaconda, miniconda

I have to use *Anaconda* provided compilers and their *Boost* package to compile my C++ code. I have a problem such that I do not know how to link properly during the compilation command.

To begin with: I create a dedicated anaconda env. with the following packages:

```
    - boost-cpp=1.77.0
    - compilers=1.3.0
```

These packages may be found here:

- https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/compilers
- https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/boost-cpp

Upon env. activation: double check which compiler I use:

```
$ which g++
/usr/share/miniconda3/envs/MYNAME/bin/g++
```

And then I would like to compile, but I don't know how to include boost libraries.
When I run:

```
$ g++ workflow/src/CODE.cpp -o workflow/bin/CODE -lm
```

Of course I get:

```
CODE.h:10:10: fatal error: boost/property_tree/info_parser.hpp: No such file or directory
   10 | #include <boost/property_tree/info_parser.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I have worked it out.
Although it might be useful for others so let's keep the solution in here:

```
g++ workflow/src/CODE.cpp -o workflow/bin/CODE -I$HOME/miniconda3/envs/MYNAME/include -lm
```

Comment: it would also work if you had (like me) a `boost` installation in the root of miniconda3 dir `$HOME/miniconda3/include`, and if you added `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/miniconda3/include` followed by `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to your `~/.bash_profile` then it would be automatically linked to all your new environments